# How do you make an Array of Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, vb.net

I would like to create an Array of Regular Expressions in Visual Basic .NET. How do I go about doing this? I know how to make a single Regular Expression like this:

```
Dim exampleRegex1 As Regex = New Regex("\s+\d")
Dim exampleRegex2 As Regex = New Regex("\s+\d\w")
Dim exampleRegex3 As Regex = New Regex("\s+\d\w\s")
```

Now how do I put all three of those into an Array of Regular Expressions in one line of code?

Comment: Like `Dim arr = { New Regex(...), New Regex(..), New Regex(..) }`?

Comment: See [How to: Initialize an Array Variable in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/how-to-initialize-an-array-variable)

Comment: @MarkS Peter B comment will help, you were asking `create an Array of Regular Expressions`, that link directly addresses how to create an Array, what you put in them doesn't matter, it's still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim exampleRegexArray As Array = {New Regex("\s\w\d"), New Regex("\s\w\d+"), New Regex("\s\w\d\s+")}
```

I figured it out myself.

Comment: It should be `Dim exampleRegexArray() As Regex = {New Regex("\s\w\d"), New Regex("\s\w\d+"), New Regex("\s\w\d\s+")}` If you have`Option Strict On` with your own code and try to change an element, you'll get a "late binding" error. To write less problematic code which is easier to debug, almost everone here would suggest that either add `Option Strict On` at the top of all your code, or change it to the default in Tools --> Options --> Projects And Solutions --VB Defaults. For the available options, the usual choices are On,On,Binary,Off. Have a search for what these do. Cheers.